# Cucumber - UI and API implementation of the same scenario

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumberjs

One thing that I really like about behave ( https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ) is that you can use the stage flag and it will run different step implementations for each one. If you pass the flag --stage=ui, then all step implementations inside ui_steps will run.
I don't want to be stuck with behave, but I didn't see this feature in other runner ( like cucumber.js or even cucumber for java)
Any ideia on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible in cucumberjs. You can pass the location of step deps for cucumber runner. If you have step definitions in separate folders for api and ui tests, you can change your configuration accordingly in your npm script or configuration of the automation tool being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two sets of support code and specify which to use via the CLI with [`--require`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#requiring-support-files). Like many things this is easier to manage using [profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#profiles).

Aslak (the creator of Cucumber) has a good talk where he is doing something similar to this, using different support code against the same features and steps to test different parts of the stack:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUclXYMDI94